# Service fabric deployment works from Visual studio, but PS script from output doesn't work in a Powershell window

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

Same deploy package, same cluster, no security. If I deploy through VS2015 everything goes swimmingly. If I watch the output in VS, I can see what PS script it is executing and with what parameters. If I copy that script to a powershell window (running as admin) and execute it there, I get the below error

```
WARNING: Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection : Cluster connection instance is null
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service
Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:143 char:16
+         [void](Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection)
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestClusterConnection
```

Why would the same script with the same parameters work in VS and not in Powershell?

Comment: VS likely runs `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` beforehand! I believe most of these `Connect` commandlets are scoped per PS instance. So a new PS window won't have the previous connection stored. Try running this before your command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/connect-servicefabriccluster?view=azureservicefabricps

Comment: @Mardoxx That does seem to be it. Funny it never required that before the most recent update Would be nice if the deploy script ran that automatically... now I have to go into my publish file to get the endpoint address on the build server so i can call this first.